# Are there any good big data demo/example applications out there?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, redis, bigdata

I'm looking for a multi server big data sample application, which can be used (a) to experiment with installing and configuring a big data application, and (b) as an example starting point for developing such an application - editing the code, making some changes,etc... In most technologies (e.g. Java EE), such applications are very common, and are very useful as a starting point.
If it can be used for benchmarking, even better.

If it uses one (or more) of Hadoop, Cassandra, HBase, MongoDB, Hive, Redis it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean applications like Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, google+ etc..

Comment: I mean like a demo application I can go and install and play with...

Comment: Why would some one do that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use TeraSort, the benchmarking test packaged with Hadoop. It sorts terabytes of data, and is used to stress test new Hadoop clusters. It's part of the `hadoop-x.y.z-examples.jar` file that comes with a Hadoop install.

To use it, generate data into HDFS using Teragen, then run Terasort.